# Running 2 neo4j clusters across 3 nodes (2 instances on same node)

Tags: neo4j

we want to run 2 neo4j clusters across 3 nodes - this means we need to run 2 neo4j instances on single host, each using different IP address and/or port.

LISTENING ON SPECIFIC IPs:

When we try to listen on IP1:5001 (without even starting second neo4j instances on any host...) all 3 nodes try to form the cluster on it's own - so first one forms new cluster, and the 2dn and 3rd should just join the cluster, but they also try to form their own cluster...

So, we had to leave it on 0.0.0.0:5001 and ofcourse this works - but this is pain, since we want to i.e. have haproxy listening on 127.0.0.1:4747 forwarding traffi to IP1:4747 or similar...

CHANING PORTS:

Also, we tried for 2 instances on single host, by changing ports: 0.0.0.0:5001, then 0.0.0.0:15001 - and this works fine, until we manually reboot one host, after that that rebooted host simply can't join cluster...

What is the supported/proposed setup to have 2 completely separate neo4j HA instances running on single host ?

This is neo4j 2.0.3 stable...

Thanks,
Andrija

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run a setup like this is to use e.g. port number 5001 for one cluster and force the other cluster onto seperate port numbers:

cluster1:

```
ha.server_id = 1 // set 2 and 3 for other machines
ha.initial_hosts=ip_1:5001,ip_2:5001,ip_3:5001
ha.cluster_server=:5001
ha.server=:6001
```

cluster2:

```
ha.server_id = 1 // set 2 and 3 for other machines
ha.initial_hosts=ip_1:7001,ip_2:7001,ip_3:7001
ha.cluster_server=:7001
ha.server=:8001
```

Of course you need to set the port for REST requests in `neo4j-server.properties` to different values as well, e.g. 7474 and 8474.

Haproxy is then configured according the [reference manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-haproxy.html).